# psql doesn't allow to input cyrillic symbols

Tags: debian, postgresql

I have a server with postgresql 8.4 installed on it. But when I try to insert some data in russian, for example:

```
UPDATE category set question = '[there should be russian symbols]' WHERE id = 1;
```

terminal doesn't allow me to type russian symbols.

Here is piece of postgresql.conf file with locales:

```
lc_messages = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
lc_monetary = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
lc_numeric = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
lc_time = 'ru_RU.UTF-8'
```

Here is locale command output:

```
LANG=ru_RU.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=ru_RU.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="ru_RU.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=ru_RU.UTF-8
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If you cannot type Cyrillic symbols in your terminal, it's not a PostgreSQL problem, it's an issue with your operating system configuration. Can you type them at the normal bash command line, or into a text editor like nano?

Comment: No, it's psql problem, because when I try to type cyrillic symbols in terminal, not PostgreSQL, it works.

Comment: When you say "PostgreSQL" do you mean the `psql` command line program that runs in a terminal? Or do you mean PgAdmin-III? Or something else? When you say you "can't type" them - is there  any error? Does the wrong text appear? or does nothing at all appear?

Comment: What happens if  you store the data in an sql file and run that, instead of typing it in?

Comment: When I execute an sql file with my cyrillic data it works. Thank you [Jenny-D](http://serverfault.com/users/120438/jenny-d)

Comment: Executing queries in file - a reason to bypass the problem but not to fix it, I can't understand why I can't type cyrillic symbols.

Comment: If you try connecting with `psql`again,, check to see what ENCODING is set to (by issuing the command `\set ENCODING`.

Comment: `server_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8`
`client_encoding 
-----------------
 UTF8`
both encodings are UTF8, I think it's correct.

Comment: Darn, I was hoping that would show something obvious. I am stumped.

Comment: This doesn't make a lot of sense. If you can type Cyrillic in the terminal it should be possible to type it in `psql` too. A more detailed description of the problem  per my prev comment would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but on postgresql 9.3.

The problem was in what library load first. In my case it was

```
/usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin
```

with symlink:

```
ldd /usr/lib/postgresql/9.3/bin/psql 
libedit.so.2 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libedit.so.2 (0x00007f1b54ac2000)
```

If you run psql like this:

```
LD_PRELOAD=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3 psql
```

then you can input cyrillic symbols.